# Как программно изменить уровень громкости в OS X?

Tags: cocoa, macos, objective-c, c++11, qt

Как программно изменить звук в системе OS X? Мне преимущества желательно использовать инструменты Qt/C++, но можно и Objective-C. В какую сторону, так сказать "копат", ведь система OS X сильно закрыта, наверное необходимо использовать свои какие-то API или как?

Comment: Можно использовать AppleScript

Comment: Какой именно звук имеется в виду, уточните, пожалуйста.

Comment: @VioLet, звук колонок, что бы к примеру можно было регулировать громкость звука при просмотре видео на сторонней программе.

Comment: @derkode то есть вы говорите про общий *уровень громкости* в системе?

Comment: Да - имеется ввиду общая громкость.

Comment: (http://cocoadev.com/SoundVolume)(http://cocoadev.com/SoundVolume) (http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/controlling-system-output-volume-with-the-mpvolumeview-class-part-one/)(http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/controlling-system-output-volume-with-the-mpvolumeview-class-part-one/) (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147133/detect-when-the-system-volume-changes-on-mac)(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147133/detect-when-the-system-volume-changes-on-mac) Надеюсь поможет

Answer (score 1):

Как уже говорилось, можно обойтись скриптом.

```
#import <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        execlp("osascript", "osascript", "-e", "set volume 5", NULL);
        return 0;
}
```

Шкала идёт от 0 до 10.